# how to load .arff format file to matlab

Tags: matlab, weka

Is there any package to load .arff format file into matlab?
The .arff format is used in [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/index.html) for running machine learning algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are a few MATLAB interfaces for WEKA files on MATLAB File Exchange, I normally use this one: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21204-matlab-weka-interface where you have a saveARFF() and a loadARFF() functions.

Comment: any examples on how it is used?

Comment: If you unzip the fileexchange files into your working directory you can use loadARFF in this way:
data = loadARFF('myfile.arf').

Comment: I get an error but i ll check again. I have unzipped it and added the folder with subfolders in the path, by clicking the button "set path". Is it correct? Do i have to do anything else so as to import the toolkit?

Answer (score 8):

Since [Weka is a Java library](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code), you can directly use the API it exposes to read ARFF files:

```
%## paths
WEKA_HOME = 'C:\Program Files\Weka-3-7';
javaaddpath([WEKA_HOME '\weka.jar']);
fName = [WEKA_HOME '\data\iris.arff'];

%## read file
loader = weka.core.converters.ArffLoader();
loader.setFile( java.io.File(fName) );
D = loader.getDataSet();
D.setClassIndex( D.numAttributes()-1 );

%## dataset
relationName = char(D.relationName);
numAttr = D.numAttributes;
numInst = D.numInstances;

%## attributes
%# attribute names
attributeNames = arrayfun(@(k) char(D.attribute(k).name), 0:numAttr-1, 'Uni',false);

%# attribute types
types = {'numeric' 'nominal' 'string' 'date' 'relational'};
attributeTypes = arrayfun(@(k) D.attribute(k-1).type, 1:numAttr);
attributeTypes = types(attributeTypes+1);

%# nominal attribute values
nominalValues = cell(numAttr,1);
for i=1:numAttr
    if strcmpi(attributeTypes{i},'nominal')
        nominalValues{i} = arrayfun(@(k) char(D.attribute(i-1).value(k-1)), 1:D.attribute(i-1).numValues, 'Uni',false);
    end
end

%## instances
data = zeros(numInst,numAttr);
for i=1:numAttr
    data(:,i) = D.attributeToDoubleArray(i-1);
end

%## visualize data
parallelcoords(data(:,1:end-1), ...
    'Group',nominalValues{end}(data(:,end)+1), ...
    'Labels',attributeNames(1:end-1))
title(relationName)
```

[image: parallel_coordinates]

You can even directly use its functionality from MATLAB. An example:

```
%## classification
classifier = weka.classifiers.trees.J48();
classifier.buildClassifier( D );
fprintf('Classifier: %s %s\n%s', ...
    char(classifier.getClass().getName()), ...
    char(weka.core.Utils.joinOptions(classifier.getOptions())), ...
    char(classifier.toString()) )
```

The output C4.5 decision tree:

```
Classifier: weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25 -M 2
J48 pruned tree
------------------

petalwidth <= 0.6: Iris-setosa (50.0)
petalwidth > 0.6
|   petalwidth <= 1.7
|   |   petallength <= 4.9: Iris-versicolor (48.0/1.0)
|   |   petallength > 4.9
|   |   |   petalwidth <= 1.5: Iris-virginica (3.0)
|   |   |   petalwidth > 1.5: Iris-versicolor (3.0/1.0)
|   petalwidth > 1.7: Iris-virginica (46.0/1.0)

Number of Leaves  :     5

Size of the tree :  9
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to load a file stored in "arff" format into Matlab, and don't need any other functionality from Weka, just remove the header part of your "arff" file (those attribute definitions), and save the file as csv format (you should replace class values with a numeric equivalences), and then use the built-in "csvread" function of Matlab. This way there is no need to find a third party package.

Answer (score 2):

```
M = importdata('filename.arff');
```

very slow for large files, but it works (tested in MATLAB 2010b)

Comment: This is hard to believe, given that the matlab documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html doesn't call out arff.  Unless matlab's `importdata` dumps all header/attribute information?

Answer (score -1):

[Searching the MATLAB Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=arff) reveals some possibilities.  In particular, the results from [Durga Lal Shrestha](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24839-mweka-running-machine-learning-tool-weka-from-matlab) and [Gerald Augusto Corzo Perez](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24751-run-weka-from-matlab) look promising, though I haven't tried either.

Answer (score -1):

If the methods mentioned above do not work, and header information is required, load the arff file in weka, then select save as option and save the data using csv file format.